# Magento 1.9 template file calling from base and not from my custom theme

Tags: magento-1.9, template

In Magento 1.9 I have created my custom theme.

Also, I have created one new module in the 'local' code pool.

Everything workes fine but the template files are loading from the base like

```
frontend/base/default/template/training/customer/view.phtml
```

it should be load from

```
frontend/allure/default/template/training/customer/view.phtml
```

this is my layout.xml

```
app/design/frontend/allure/dream/layout/training.xml

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<layout version="0.1.0">

    <customer_account>
        <reference name="customer_account_navigation">
            <action method="addLink" translate="label" module="training">
                <name>training</name>
                <path>training/customer/view</path>
                <label>Training</label>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </customer_account>

  <training_customer_view>
            <update handle="customer_account"/>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="training/customer" name="view.training" template="training/customer/view.phtml"/>
            </reference>
   </training_customer_view>

</layout>
```

If anyone knows why this is happening>

Comment: is this the custom theme is applying to current store?

Answer (score 0):

place the phtml file in frontend/allure/dream/template/training/customer/view.phtml

i think the problem is that you put the phtml file and xml file in diffrent sub theme folder